# Can't load bootstrap css file

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a django project in pycharm and I'm trying to use bootstrap blog example(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/blog/). I came across a problem: bootstrap.min.css file is not working properly, when I link it like this it works properly,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but when I download this file then save it in my_app/static/my_app/bootstrap.min.css and link it like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogs/bootstrap.min.css' %}" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

it doesn't work, the django development server is properly loading the css file

```
[14/Jan/2020 19:04:26] "GET /static/blogs/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

but it just doesn't have any effect on the site apperance, the blog.css file does have effect as I can see fonts and a few thing change but the bootstrap.min.css file just doesn't.

Comment: Are you following this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/ Try renaming the href to `{% static 'my_app/bootstrap.min.css' %}`

Comment: If you open your console you'll see an error in which the browser tells you it wasn't able to find the resource. By looking at where it is trying to download the file from will help you understand how you need to modify the `href` attribute so it resolves at the path where the resource is located.

Comment: @themanatuf I'm following the docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files, my href is already {% static 'my_app/bootstrap.min.css' %}, my app_name is blogs so the path is href="{% static 'blogs/bootstrap.min.css' %}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to log your path if it return where your `bootstrap.min.css` file exists.
Then check if your browser's cache is clear if not then give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the console in browser, as @tao said, turns out the problem was the

```
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
```

in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blogs/bootstrap.min.css' %}" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Thank your for your help